# Ajax POST call 400 Bad Request / Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header not present even postman said it is set while doing an options request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, webservice-client

I want to call a rest webservice which is written in JAVA and I know that Access-Control-Allow-Origin has to be set if it's a cross-domain request and when I'm doing the request as

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: clocking,
    headers:
    {
        // some headers
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr)
    {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});`

I get 400 - Bad Request - the reason is because the object is not in JSON format, I guess.

But when I do the request as

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(clocking),
    headers:
    {
        // some headers
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr)
    {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});`

I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not present but when I do an OPTIONS request via postman I see Access-Control-Allow-Origin →* is set in headers.

[image: postman]

I'm also wondering why Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Max-Age is set twice. Could this cause an error so that I'm not able to retrieve the Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Does anyone have any hints? I think there's is a server-side issue but unfortunately I don't have the server-side code because it's written by another person.

Comment: clocking is array, or object?

Comment: clocking is an object

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late answer, but for other people who might have the same issue, here is my guess.

First, if the request fails itself, the server side will not get to the point of setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for response, so you get response without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Second, Error 400 means that `The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the data stream sent by the client was 'malformed'`. And my best guess is that your data didn't follow the rules(e.g.  API specification) on the server-side.